# Overwriting CSS classes and ids

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm using the Gantry Framework for WordPress and I'd like to completely remove the formatting. For example, this is some of the styling applied to one of the positions.

```
#rt-top-surround {
    background-color: #363636;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top,#3b3b3b,#2e2e2e);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,0 0,0 100%,from(#3B3B3B),to(#2E2E2E));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,#3B3B3B,#2E2E2E);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top,#3b3b3b,#2e2e2e);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom,#3B3B3B,#2E2E2E);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ff3b3b3b',         endColorstr='#ff2e2e2e', GradientType=0);
    color: #ADADAD;
    text-shadow: 0 2px 3px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
```

What I do to get rid of it (in the child style.css file) is the following:

```
#rt-top-surround {
    background-color: #AAA89C;
    background-image: none;
    background-repeat: inherit;
    filter: progid: none;
    color: inherit;
    border-bottom: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    text-shadow: none;
}
```

Is there a better way? Maybe a catch all way of removing the styling? I can't remove it from the main style.css file as any future updates would bring it back.

I'm fine with the way that I am handling it, I guess I'm just wondering if there is an easier way to overwrite styles like this?

**EDIT**
Seems to be some confusion, sorry for not being clear. I guess I'm looking for something like the CSS all shorthand property that resets all attributes. So instead of having to write out each attribute and set it to the default, I would only have to write

```
#rt-top-surround {
    all: initial;
}
```

And that would save me a bunch of coding. I don't think this property is quite ready to go yet, though.

Comment: I can't think of a better way to overwrite it, but in this case can't you just remove the styles in the original stylesheet?

Comment: Please see my link below. Its a common wp fix.

Comment: JoeJ, if I remove the styles in the original sheet and then an update to the theme or framework occurs, it would put those styles back.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to create another style sheet and set it to take priority over all other style sheets. override.css Please see the link below; I would suggest option 2.

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/overriding-all-other-stylesheets

Comment: It might not work with all browsers. !important is the safest way to do overrides.

Comment: Right, could do that also... but I guess I'm looking for a way to NOT have to default out each attribute. Using the above method, I'd still have to write out each attribute and set them to there default to get rid of the original styling.

Comment: Well you would only have to do it once and its done then. Either way when over riding styles they have to be written out once...

Comment: But you have to do it once and not worry about updates going forward.

Answer (score -1):

You can use "!important" property. For example ..

```
#rt-top-surround {
    background-image: none !important;
}
```

This will override the main Stylesheet. You can place this into a separate override.css file.

Read about "!important" here: http://webdesign.about.com/od/css/f/blcssfaqimportn.htm

Comment: I guess I'm looking for a way to completely remove the styling instead of setting it to its default. I know about !important, and I've used that here and there, but that doesn't keep me from having to write out each attribute and set each one to its default.

Comment: When Wordpress updates it brings them back. The best way is to add a new style sheet to overide all other stylesheets.

Comment: hmm can't read your mind. So next time please do include that you are aware of "!important" tag.

Comment: Sure Kirill, but your post didn't answer my question, you were just point out another way to override styles. I'm not asking for other ways to override styles... I am asking for a way to REMOVE styles easily without having to override them. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Right. But as you've pointed out, any updates bring them back, thus you can't really remove the styles. I was trying to point out that by writing the overrides, you just do it once and forget about it.